# Invalid Character Constant in Java when i build a string?

Tags: java

```
String searchString = '{"jql": "project","startAt": 0,"maxResults":1 ,"fields": ["id","key","summary = UI Test nn nn OAADI: Dispatching of activities to field technicians"]}';
```

I use that string to query an search for jira rest api.

Comment: Strings in Java start with `"`. Characters start with `'`.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: When does the error occur? is that error returned by the JIRA API? do you get a stackTrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
String searchString = "{\"jql\": \"project\",\"startAt\": 0,\"maxResults\":1 ,\"fields\": [\"id\",\"key\",\"summary = UI Test nn nn OAADI: Dispatching of activities to field technicians\"]}";
```

In Java, `string` requires double quotes `"`, `char` requires single quotes `'`.  To embed quotes in a string like you want, you have to escape them by adding a `\` in front.

You can find all the juicy details about escaping [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: thanks that is what i looking for, now i have a problem with de jql :))

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings are enclosed within double quotes like "this", not 'this'.